# complex querys in Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, activerecord, eloquent

I want to migrate a old site of statistics on KBPHP to Laravel 5. I'm wondering, what is the Laravel way to handle this query? I mean, on ActiveRecords I had to go directly to write the query by hand, there were no way to handle it.
Maybe exist something similar to write this on Laravel or a way to write by hand
!!

This is the query:

```php
public function agresiones_get_genero($year){
    $query  = " SELECT tsagredido.id, tsagredido.tsagredido, 
            SUM( IF (agredidos.gen_id = 1, 1, 0) ) m, SUM( IF  (agredidos.gen_id = 2, 1, 0) ) f,
            SUM( IF (agredidos.gen_id = 3, 1, 0) ) l, SUM( IF (agredidos.gen_id = 4, 1, 0) ) n 
            FROM agredidos
            INNER JOIN tsagredido ON agredidos.tsagredido_id = tsagredido.id
            INNER JOIN alertas ON agredidos.alertas_id = alertas.id
            WHERE alertas.anio = $year AND alertas.publicada_id = 1 GROUP BY agredidos.tsagredido_id";
               return $this->find_all_by_sql($query);
    }
```

Translate agredidos as **assaulted**, 
**tsagredidos** is like say "type of ocupation of the assaulted"

There are 4 tables involve, **tsagredidos**, **gender**, **agredidos** and **alerts**.

Were **alerts** is related to **agredidos**, and **agredidos** contains the relation to **tsagredidos** and **gender**.

**gender** contains the male (m), female (f), Lesbians, gays, Transexuals (l) and none (n) options, while tsagredidos is a list of types of ocupation of the **agredidos**

And they are filtered by the incoming variable of the year of the **alert**

http://alertas.clibrehonduras.com/reportes/sujeto_agredido_genero

Thank you for any help. It may be an easy solution but I'm a complete newbie on Laravel ENV.

Comment: DB does the job, nevermind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Agredidos::join('tsagredido','agredidos.tsagredido_id','=','tsagredido.id')
    ->join('alertas','agredidos.alertas_id','=','alertas.id')
    ->where('alertas.anio',$year)
    ->where('alertas.publicada_id',1)
    ->groupBy('agredidos.tsagredido_id')
    ->get([
        'tsagredido.id,',
        'tsagredido.tsagredido',
        DB::raw('SUM( IF (agredidos.gen_id = 1, 1, 0) ) m'),
        DB::raw('SUM( IF  (agredidos.gen_id = 2, 1, 0) ) f'),
        DB::raw('SUM( IF (agredidos.gen_id = 3, 1, 0) ) l'),
        DB::raw('SUM( IF (agredidos.gen_id = 4, 1, 0) ) n )

    ]);
```

or

```
DB::table('agredidos')->join('tsagredido','agredidos.tsagredido_id','=','tsagredido.id')
    ->join('alertas','agredidos.alertas_id','=','alertas.id')
    ->where('alertas.anio',$year)
    ->where('alertas.publicada_id',1)
    ->groupBy('agredidos.tsagredido_id')
    ->get([
        'tsagredido.id,',
        'tsagredido.tsagredido',
        DB::raw('SUM( IF (agredidos.gen_id = 1, 1, 0) ) m'),
        DB::raw('SUM( IF  (agredidos.gen_id = 2, 1, 0) ) f'),
        DB::raw('SUM( IF (agredidos.gen_id = 3, 1, 0) ) l'),
        DB::raw('SUM( IF (agredidos.gen_id = 4, 1, 0) ) n )

    ]);
```

This might work for u :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know you can apply that "->get" for tha array results, and if I guess rigth, on the view is something like $agredidos->m, for the DB::raw(()m).... Somebody add a vote+ from me here!!!